# Quiero hacer una pantalla de inicio para navegar los objetos de mi aplicación en Libre Office Base

Tags: libreoffice-calc

Desarrolle los objetos de una aplicación en Libre Office Base (Tablas, Formularios, consultas, Informes) y deseo tener una pantalla de inicio a través de la cual navegare todos los objetos, mi pregunta es, ¿Dónde le digo a Base cual es la pantalla de inicio para la aplicación?, ¡alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Pruebe estas ideas: https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/how-to-i-create-a-base-application-that-will-start-up-on-a-switchboard-form/26359